# Circular class references bad practice?

Tags: c#, oop, dependencies

Lately someone told me how circular references in the form of Class 1 calls Class 2 calls Class 1 is considered extremely bad practice, and I just can't get my head around that. I mean, if those classes are in 2 different projects I completely understand the problematic, but can that be bad if they're in the same project? And in some cases... how exactly are you to prevent that?

For example: I have a server of some kind. Clients connect to it, and the Client, which derives from a socket, or holds it, takes care of the network stuff, and also some information like account id, etc. This Client calls a packet handler, when there's something new, and now the packet handler needs information from the client and has to send information back. I pass the Client to the packet handler, so it can call it's send functions, etc.

The person who was concerned about this thought this was the mentioned bad practice, and tried to not do this at all, even though I've rarely seen servers, especially big ones, who kept all the packet handling inside the client class. Additionally, you might go further than the handler, and call more classes. It's a mess to keep all that inside the Client. So... is *this* really bad practice?

If it is, how would one go around it? To get this done, you'd need a more or less complicated collection of objects in Client, that you can pass down, without having to call functions of Client again...

Like I said, I can't really wrap my head around this "problem". Can someone help me out?

Comment: F# makes circular class references real fun.

Comment: Look in the "Related" questions list. --------->  looks like there are several that could help answer the question.

Comment: In most cases I find that I can restructure such code to a consumer/producer problem which eliminates one half the coupling resulting in a cleaner design overall. In the cases where that doesn't work out, I use *specific interfaces* (which I try to do anyway); once again, I find these can minimize "circular references" to the core required aspects and make the program more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When people talk about circular references, they usually talk about project/dll references. These are problematic when it comes to resolving references, and Visual Studio won't let you add circular references.

But you're referring not to project structure but to the architecture, and here things are a bit more complicated. There's nothing inherently wrong with classes calling each other. In fact, this is implicit in the design of features like callbacks and events in .NET - when you register to an event, you're effectively calling a class that will later call you back with the event handler.

However, this form of circular calling is relatively decoupled. The server doesn't have an EXPLICIT reference to the client, but only the list of subscribed clients that are called. If you hadn't done that, but rather had the packet handler, for instance, hold an explicit reference to the client, then those two classes would be tightly coupled - the packet handler relies on the specific implementation of the client and vise versa.

Why is this bad? This violates the principle of Separation of Concerns, one of the most fundamental concept in programming, in my opinion. The client should know how to handle client operations, the packet handler should handle packet operations, and neither should know how the other one works, and communicate only through well-defined and specific interfaces.

Let's take a very stripped-down hypothetical situation that's based on your OP, that has circular references:
The client calls the packet handler's `Send()` method. The packet handler now starts the connection, then discovers it needs a username/password. It calls a method on the client to get it, then sends it to the server, gets a response, then calls back to the client to return it.

In this case, the packet handler is now tied to the client's implementation. It requires the client to have a GetCredentials() method and a MessageReceived method to call back to it. Now imagine a more decoupled scenario:

The client first signs up for the handler's ResponseReceived event. Now the client calls the packet handler's Send() method. The packet handler needs authentication, so it fails - it throws an exception or returns an error code saying "can't connect". The client gets this response, and calls again, this time using Send(username, password) method. It succeeds, gets a response, and raises the ResponseReceived event, sending the response to whomever's subscribed to it.

This allows the packet handler to be reused in other contexts, from other client. It allows changes to be made internally to the client or the handler with less effect on other components. It makes for simpler, more easily maintained code. And that's good. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are certainly situations where a circular class reference isn't at all bad. There's always an instantiation issue (chicken or egg). Always remember there allready is two way communication between objects. You could make the client wait for the nextmessage by calling a function that returns when there is a new message.

But it is a point where you should stop and think. Especially in the following situations (there are more but these are at the top of my head):

- When you are notifying a class some action has happend **->** make it an event.
- When it's a one to one relationship **->** should the types be merged into one.
- When your class extends the functionality of the other **->** inherit from it in stead of passing a reference.

In your situation client <-> packet handler. I probably wouldn't keep the circular reference there. I would likely write a controller for both classes which acts as a proxy for information between them. I would also not store the account id in the client object. It rubs a bit against the single responsibility principle I like to adhere to. I would likely end up with something like this:

- Client -> socket (responsible for network stuff)
- ClientHandler (responsible for controlling the flow)

  - Client
  - PacketHandler
  - Additional information
- PacketHandler

Answer (score 2):

Classes within the same *package* should be considered highly cohesive (assuming your package structure is correct!) and can have tighter coupling. Within the package, circular relationships - if required - are OK, but will benefit from a design based on *specific interfaces* (as noted by previous posters).

*Across package boundaries*, cohesion is naturally lower and coupling should be kept as low as possible: definitely *no* circular relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extract the functionalities that A calls on B and the ones that B calls on A and then encapsulate them in a Class Library C, that the other libraries can invoke without problems. Obviously, C mustn't have reference neither to A nor B.